# Debugging error 000278 from Append and Merge tools in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, geoprocessing

Append and Merge tools issues in Arc 10. keep getting error 000278 - failed on input OID ...... (could not write value to one field or the other).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Never had this problem in Arc 9.3, where if the value did not fit, it would get chopped off.

Comment: error 000278 - A reports file containing the IDs and an error list for the rejected annotation features has been created in your temp directory

Comment: Here's the [page for this error](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#//00vp0000001p000278.htm) for 10.0.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. the field length of the target feature class was too little. I created a new feature class in arccatalog with a greater field length and then load data into it. you get the same result as with merge and append, but in a new feature class.